# Integrating Zoho as a service inside my mobile App

Tags: mobile, zoho

I am working on a Employee All in one Solution Mobile App where the product will be having a sign sign on authentication and once the user is authenticated he will be having features like Employee Feedback,Awards etc and one among the features are accessing Zoho for time tracking and other tools so we have decided to integrate a webview which will be redirecting the user to zoho pages but how do we pass the authentication token (Our backend will authenticate with the Zoho service to provide the authentication token).Can anyone help on how do we achieve this and is this the right way or is there any other better solution.